# Compare two relations with postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate

I'm looking to compare two entries by it's join table and return a percentage of matching

The join table look like:

```
|recipe_id|ingredient_id|
|---------|-------------|
|    1    |      1      |
|    1    |      2      |
|    1    |      3      |
|-----------------------|
|    2    |      4      |
|    2    |      10     |
|    2    |      20     |
|-----------------------|
```

If I provide an array of `ingredient_id` => `[1,2,3]`, the expected result is

```
|recipe_id|match_percent|
|---------|-------------|
|    1    |      100    |
|-----------------------|
|    2    |      0      |
|-----------------------|
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: GROUP BY recipe_id etc. But why  0 % for recipe 2 in you example? Ingredient 3 is in that recipe.

Comment: typo for recipe 2, updated answer

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is that have the array as a lookup table and join with that to find the count

```
select t.recipe_id, 
count(t.ingredient_id)/(select count(*) from lookup_table)*100 as match_percent 
from
(
select t1.recipe_id,t1.ingredient_id from table as t1 inner join lookup_table as t2
on t1.ingredient_id=t2.ingredient_id
) as t 
group by t1.recipe_id
```